# Load Contract From Address Remix

Tags: remix, bsc

I deployed a smart contract and was working on it when my laptop decided to shut down, my saved smart contract was gone.

I have my contract address and my contract source code. However I can't seem to load the contract from the address.

Anyone know what to do?

[image]

Comment: idk what is wrong with that button... have you tried another browser or to build remix locally on your computer instead of using the webpage?

Comment: can you compile the contract with remix?

Answer (score 3):

Let me cite from the [documentation](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html#deploy-ataddress):

> To use *AtAddress*, you need to have the source code or ABI of the
> deployed contract in the active tab of the editor. When using the
> source code, it must be compiled with the same compilation settings as
> the deployed contract that you are trying access.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the correct contract from the dropdown menu just above the At Address box.